# Convert Daily dates to weekly using a specific first day of the week

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime, pandas-groupby

I am currently working on grouping/aggregating data based on date range for a weekly plot.

Below is how my dataframe looks like for Daily data:

| daily_dates | registered | attended |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 02/10/2022 | 0 | 0 |
| 02/09/2022 | 0 | 0 |
| 02/08/2022 | 1 | 0 |
| 02/07/2022 | 1 | 0 |
| 02/06/2022 | 20 | 06 |
| 02/05/2022 | 05 | 03 |
| 02/04/2022 | 15 | 12 |
| 02/03/2022 | 10 | 08 |
| 02/02/2022 | 10 | 05 |

The first day of the week I'd want is Sunday.

My current code to perform weekly group is:

```
weekly_df = weekly_df.resample('w').sum().reset_index()
```

The output I am desiring is:

| weekly_dates | registered | attended |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 02/06/2022 | 22 | 06 |
| 01/30/2022 | 40 | 28 |

A bit of explanation about desired output - the reason for `02/06/2022` & `01/30/2022` is that both these dates are start date of that respective week which is a sunday. And for the week of `01/30/2022` only `02/05/2022|05|03, 02/04/2022, 02/03/2022, 02/02/2022`  dates are considered as those are the one's in the daily dataframe.

My current implementation follows the instructions provided [here](https://raj26kumar.medium.com/convert-daily-data-to-weekly-data-without-losing-names-of-other-column-using-python-pandas-e2aa001a3691).

I am looking for any suggestion to achieve my **Desired Output**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df.resample('W-SUN', label='left', closed='left').sum().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  daily_dates  registered  attended
0  2022-01-30          40        28
1  2022-02-06          22         6
```